# Site layout breaks at some resolutions

Tags: html, css

I create a website template but when I set the size, my website breaks.

My resolution is 1600x900, and when I open template on another monitor with another size , my website breaks.

The code:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 1600px;
  height: auto;
}
```

My breaks website:
[image: Breaks website]

My deffault website without *width* and *height*
[image: Without breaks]

Comment: My breaks website http://i.imgur.com/zVyGukZ.jpg
My deffault website http://i.imgur.com/gadlO20.jpg

Comment: Don't ever never use `* selector` like that... That's mean that everything in your `html code` will have those properties.

Comment: apply width only to body and not to * (all) the elements

Comment: * is a global selector. It selects all the elements.

Comment: Without HTML, we have no clue what you are trying to do. Also, like gmo said, you are applying `width:1600px` to everything on your webpage.

Comment: What you need here is `media queries`. and also fix your code... because you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`*` in CSS is a wildcard. Therefore, when you set

```
* { width:1600px; }
```

you set *every element in the page* to a width of 1600px. Instead, set just the body:

```
body { width:1600px; }
```

or create a `<div>` with a specific ID to encapsulate your web page:

```
div#main { width:1600px; }
```